# Fastreports custom preview problem

Tags: delphi, report, bmp, fastreport

I encounter problem on FastReports, it will not print correctly on pages which contain Korean character. It hapens only on Printer HP K5300 jet, T test it using rave and having no problem. I think it a bug for fast reports. I already convert all my reports from rave to FastReports and dont have plan to moved back.

I am planning to get the generated pages as images without saving it to hard drive and then generate a new preports. this time, the generated images will be used and print. I know this solution is not good. this is worable for now While waiting for their responds.

anybody has any idea how to get the images form generated pages?

Comment: By editing your question, you've made it *harder* to understand. You've asked how to create a report image without saving it to disk, which seems to be exactly what Jachguate's answer does. What do Korean characters have to do with it? Why is your switch from Rave to Fast Reports relevant?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, yes im an having problem on korean char. only the first character will appear on the paper when printing. sorry if very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to avoid saving a lot of files, you can create a new export class to print the file just after it is created and delete it instantly.

You can create a whole new export class which print the bitmap from memory (for example, using the TPrinter class and drawing the bitmap directly in the printer canvas)... you will learn how checking the source file of the TfrxBMPExport class.

Take this untested code as an example which will guide you how to create a new class to save/print/delete:

```
type
  TBMPPrintExport = class(TfrxBMPExport)
  private
    FCurrentPage: Integer;
    FFileSuffix: string;
  protected
    function Start: Boolean; override;
    procedure StartPage(Page: TfrxReportPage; Index: Integer); override;
    procedure Save; override;
  end;


{ TBMPPrintExport }

procedure TBMPPrintExport.Save;
var
  SavedFileName: string;
begin
  inherited;
  if SeparateFiles then
    FFileSuffix := '.' + IntToStr(FCurrentPage)
  else
    FFileSuffix := '';
  SavedFileName := ChangeFileExt(FileName, FFileSuffix + '.bmp');
  //call your actual printing routine here.  Be sure your the control returns here when the bitmap file is not needed anymore.
  PrintBitmapFile(SavedFileName);
  try
    DeleteFile(SavedFileName);
  except
    //handle exceptions here if you want to continue if the file is not deleted 
    //or let the exception fly to stop the printing process.
    //you may want to add the file to a queue for later deletion
  end;
end;

function TBMPPrintExport.Start: Boolean;
begin
  inherited;
  FCurrentPage := 0;
end;

procedure TBMPPrintExport.StartPage(Page: TfrxReportPage; Index: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  Inc(FCurrentPage);
end;
```

In production code you will want to override another methods to initialize and finalize the printer job, cleaning up, etc.

Code is based on FastReport v4.0 implementation of TfrxCustomImageExport, specially for page numbering and file naming.  It may require adjustments for other FastReport versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TfrxBMPExport (frxExportImage unit) component to save the report as BMP.

For example, this code will export the report:

```
procedure ExportToBMP(AReport: TfrxReport; AFileName: String = '');
var
  BMPExport: TfrxBMPExport;

begin
  BMPExport := TfrxBMPExport.Create(nil);
  try
    BMPExport.ShowProgress := True;
    if AFileName <> '' then
    begin
      BMPExport.ShowDialog := False;
      BMPExport.FileName := AFileName;
      BMPExport.SeparateFiles := True;
    end;
    AReport.PrepareReport(True);
    AReport.Export(BMPExport);
  finally
    BMPExport.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The Export component, in this case, uses a different file name for each page.  If you pass 'c:\path\report.bmp' as the filename, the export component will generate c:\path\report.1.bmp, c:\path\report.2.bmp and such.

As usual, you can drop and manually configure the component on any form/data module if you prefer that way.

Comment: +1 thansk for your reply. i edit my question get more specific. Your solution is great. but it dont have to be save on the drv. what if it generates a 500 pages?

Comment: men, you just changed totally the premises of your question... just invalidating my answer, which was accurate for your original question.  I have to think if I want to issue a different answer here or just delete this... I feel disappointed, because I took (some or much) of my (valuable) time to try to help you and you just throw it away!  If you ask for what you don't want, I think is more respectful just to accept my answer (or not) and post a very new question.

Comment: sorry about that. i find out there is no way we can use the image directly. but saving it first.